# URLError('unknown url type: https')

Tags: python

I trying to scrape a website with beautiful soup, but I keep getting this error,URLError('unknown url type: https'), when Im trying to open the url. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling urllib, however the problem still persists. Does anyone know where could the problem lie?

```
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as ureq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as  soup

myurl = "https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video- 
Devices/Category/ID-38?pk=graphics%20card"

ureq(myurl) <- the expection is raised here
```

I tried applying referring similar questions in  stackoverflow, but they dont apply as even when the url is https://www.newegg.com, without any specical characters, the exception still persists.

Comment: Is `myurl` broken into 2 lines or is this just a formatting thing in SO?

Comment: @Carlos oops sorry i just editted it, it was a formatting problem

Comment: why is this question is tagged "beautifulsoup"?  It imports the package and then does nothing with it.